# Best way to refer to other instances of a class or other objects?

Tags: python, class

I have a Network(object) and Node(object) classes, and each node belongs to a different network (there are also link objects that connects nodes, etc, but let's ignore this). What is the best way to keep track which object is in which network and vice versa?

What I am doing now is to have a dictionary attribute in the Network(object), the keys of which are names of Node objects, and the values are the objects themselves, and also a networkidx attribute in each node class, and global networks dictionary with networkidx's as keys, and the Network objects as values.

Here's a minimal example. The network has an internal clock and when the node is activated it retrieves the time of the network and stores it as a timestamp on the node.

```
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, networkidx):
        self.networkidx = networkidx
        self.nodes = {}
        self.internalclock = 1

    def create_node(self, nodeidx):
        self.nodes[nodeidx] = Node(self.networkidx, nodeidx)

    def pass_time(self, time):
        self.internalclock = self.internalclock + time


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, networkidx, nodeidx):
        self.networkidx = networkidx
        self.nodeidx = nodeidx
        self.activation_timestamps = []

    def activate(self):
        current_time = networks[self.networkidx].internalclock
        self.activation_timestamps.append(current_time)


networks = {}
networks['net1'] = Network('net1')
networks['net1'].create_node('node1')
networks['net1'].nodes['node1'].activate()
networks['net1'].pass_time(10)
networks['net1'].nodes['node1'].activate()
print networks['net1'].nodes['node1'].activation_timestamps
```

Everything works just fine, and I have many more methods and references between nodes and the network, etc. What I am wondering if this is the best way to keep track of object relations, what are the best practices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty good way to keep track of reasonable amount of entries at one execution. But not if you want it to be persistent.

If you can order the nodes by some valuable property you got a even better way. +it can be easily persistent

For example i had this issue myself. I was trying to implement javascript function setTimeout on lua.

The way i thought is that return id is increasing by one on every call. So there's indirect method to refer to an entry.

More importantly was my usage. I only needed to see which entry is the one to call. So i did sort the entries by the execution time.

Another is to sort entries as you insert new one. When we have a ordered list. Adding new entry costs O(log(n)). By using bisection search and insert at appropriate place.